# Python make_scorer giving incorrect outputs for Root Mean Square Logarithmic Error

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, numpy

I want to generate a grid search for which I need the `scoring` parameter based on which the search will take place. I have defined the following function to provide me a `Root Mean Squared Logarithmic Error`. But I feel that the scorer is considering the greater value to be a better score, whereas it should consider the lower value as better score. Please let me know if I have defined a correct scorer.

**Function for RMSLE**

```
def score_func(y_true, y_pred, **kwargs):
  y_true = np.abs(y_true)
  y_pred = np.abs(y_pred)

  return np.sqrt(mean_squared_log_error(y_true, y_pred))

scorer = make_scorer(score_func)
```

I had to use `np.abs` in the above code, otherwise it was giving an error that RMSLE cannot be used when Target has negative values.

Comment: There's a parameter for that! `greater_is_better`, see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html  
(I would like to point out that your absolute values seem odd here; if you want log-error, you shouldn't have negative targets...but that's another issue.)

Comment: cross-posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/64155899/10495893

Answer (score 0):

The `make_scorer` function takes a `greater_is_better` parameter (bool, default=True) which defines whether 'high is good' or 'low is good'. Changing its value to False might solve the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to import the scikit-learn version to avoid bugs.

```py
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_log_error as msle

msle(y_true, y_pred, squared=False) # Calculate RMSLE
```